# Batch Find/Replace within text file with savable/editable replace lists/presets

Tags: windows, text-processing, plain-text, regex

I am looking for software for Windows that provides a lot of functionality for Find/Replace batch operations on text files in folders.

A key feature is the ability to create batch lists of find/replace operations that can be saved/reused and continually edited/refined/versioned.

RegEx would also be key. Maybe some auto-backup options would be great too.

Is there anything out there? Free or worth paying for.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is the tool you're looking for.  You can get it from GnuWin32: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm.  A `sed` script file can be created that contains the batch of find/replace operations that you want to carry out.  The `sed` commands are all text, so the script file can be easily maintained in a version control system.